# seeking out help writing a printer.cfg klipper file for a tronxy veho 600

Tags: klipper, tronxy

i recently took delivery of a tronxy veho 600, i found the standard firmware to be a major bottleneck so with the help of a raspberry pi 4b and a cr touch i am making some upgrades. unfortunately there is little to no info regarding the printer.cfg file for this model so im hoping someone on here will be able to advise.

i was lucky enough to find a file for a veho 600 but it was for a highly modified version so it wont be a straight fit for my one.

my main questions are regarding the extruder code block, following is an exerpt from the custom veho config file.

```
[extruder]
step_pin: PB1
dir_pin: !PF13
enable_pin: !PF14
microsteps: 16
rotation_distance: 22.172 # Needs to be tweaked
gear_ratio: 50:10 #50:17 # BMG Clone ratio per klipper docs
nozzle_diameter: 0.400
filament_diameter: 1.750
heater_pin: PG7
sensor_type: Generic 3950
sensor_pin: PC3
#control: pid
#pid_Kp: 20.72
#pid_Ki: 1.88
#pid_Kd: 57.18
min_temp: 0
max_temp: 320
max_extrude_only_distance: 400
max_extrude_cross_section: 50.0
min_extrude_temp: 180 # dangerous, but bowden loading is much 
easier without it
```

1. what is the definition of step pin
2. both dir_pin and enable_pin have values set but they include the ! before them, which means not. this confuses me, can anyone give any indication as to what/why this is?
3. "heater_pin: pg7" am i right in saying this is for the hot end heat block?
4. "sensor_pin: pc3" is this a temperature sensor or is it something else?
5. all code lines relevant to the pid property are commented out, what is the reason for this? do i enable them when pid tuning or should i leave them off?
6. can anyone give me an explanation as to what the last 3 lines of code do, one of them is quoted dangerous so i definately need to be sure before running.

Comment: Nice question and well presented, but... it is too broad because it contains multiple questions in one post. On Stack Exchange one issue per post is required, in order to making answering each issue simpler. I would suggest asking separate questions and linking them together using the URLs. So, before this question gets closed as being too broad (which it has already been flagged as), please [edit] it to contain just the first point, and then ask the other 5 points in different questions. I hope that makes sense. Thanks. Also, please try to fix the typos.